# Isasues with making discord bot to run on raspberry pie

Tags: python, discord, bots

1. The basic idea of this bot is to scan Tesco to find deals of 5 or more pounds compare them with the same products' Amazon prices and detail them in the discord server, the code I want to use keeps having issues, and I was wondering if anybody was able to advise me whether the code is just a write-off or if it's saveable and how, also if anyone knew of any code writing ai's for free or cheap that used prompts that would be appreciated

```
import discord
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
import aiohttp
import async_timeout
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True 

bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)

TESCO_URL = "https://www.tesco.com/groceries/"
AMAZON_URL = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/"
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'}

@slash.slash(name="search", description="Searches Tesco for deals compared to Amazon")
async def search(ctx):

    async with ctx.typing():
        deals = await get_deals(ctx)
    
    if not deals:
        await ctx.send("No deals found!") 
        return
    
    message = "Tesco Deals:"
    for deal in deals:
        name, tesco_price, amazon_price, difference = deal
        saving = f" (Save £{difference:.2f})" if difference >= 5 else ""
        message += f"\n{name} - £{tesco_price} at Tesco vs £{amazon_price} on Amazon{saving}" 

    await ctx.send(message)

async def get_deals(ctx):

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        try:
            # Scrape Tesco listings
            async with async_timeout.timeout(10):
                tesco_response = await session.get(TESCO_URL, headers=HEADERS)
                tesco_text = await tesco_response.text()
            tesco_soup = BeautifulSoup(tesco_text, 'lxml')
            tesco_listings = tesco_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-list--list-item'})
            
            deals = []
            for listing in tesco_listings:
                name = listing.find('a', {'class': 'ui__link'}).text
                tesco_price = float(re.search(r'£([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)', listing.find('div', {'class': 'price-control--price'}).text).group(1))
                
                # Search Amazon
                async with async_timeout.timeout(10):
                    params = {'k': name.replace(' ', '+')}  
                    amazon_response = await session.get(AMAZON_URL, params=params, headers=HEADERS)
                    amazon_text = await amazon_response.text()
                amazon_soup = BeautifulSoup(amazon_text, 'lxml')
                amazon_listing = amazon_soup.find('div', {'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})
                
                if amazon_listing:
                    amazon_price_tag = amazon_listing.find('span', 'a-price')
                    if amazon_price_tag:
                        amazon_price = float(amazon_price_tag.find('span', 'a-offscreen').text.replace('£', ''))
                    else:
                        continue 
                    
                    difference = amazon_price - tesco_price
                    if difference >= 5:
                        deals.append((name, tesco_price, amazon_price, difference))
        
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(f"Error: {e}")

        return deals

bot.run(os.environ['bottoken'])
```

I have changed the import discord packages? multiple times downloading different versions of discord-slash-command ect but have been struggling.

Comment: You just leaked your bot's discord token, it will be reset automatically soon and you'll have to get a new one from Discord Developer Portal.